# Listing directory sizes in Apache

Tags: apache

I'm using Apaxy for pretty directory listing in Apache.

Problem is, the folder's (including subfolders) size is not written in the generated *.html. Is there any way to achieve this by editing the .htacess or some other configuration file?

Thanks in advance.[image]

In the above screenshot, a "-" appears for the folder size.

Comment: that'd be hideously expensive, forcing apache to scan the ENTIRE subdirectory tree of that directory to calculate the size, and do it every time the page is accessed.

Comment: can't it have it cached somewhere? This is a small personal website with simple folderstructures.

Comment: the individual stat results might be in the under lying os's file cache, but apache's own scan + calculations won't be. I don't see anything in mod_index and the like that enable such an option.

Answer (score 0):

take a look at here : http://adamwhitcroft.com/apaxy/
apaxy is just theme . it does not give you extra informations about files and directories it just use some css to change the style.
and I dont think there is a way apache show the directory size.

Comment: Thank you majid8911. Apaxy is just a style for Apache listing, there are hundreds out there. The question is independent of apaxy.